# Is it possible to check if agent is idle or not ? (Teamcity API)

Tags: node.js, rest, api, teamcity

I want to figure out if my compatible agents from a specific agents pool are idle or not at real time for case i want to explicitly choose only idle agents to run via API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just run the build and TeamCity automatically select available agent.

TeamCity has some API for getting agent information

- List agents (only authorized agents are included by default): GET http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/agents
- List all connected authorized agents: GET http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/agents?locator=connected:true,authorized:true
- List all authorized agents: GET http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/agents?locator=authorized:true
- List all enabled authorized agents: GET http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/agents?locator=enabled:true,authorized:true
- List all agents (including unauthorized): GET http://teamcity:8111/app/rest/agents?locator=authorized:any

Answer (score 0):

You can check needed agent by url
[enter link description here](https://%3CTS%3E/app/rest/agents/id:3)

And then check property build in response. If it's in idle state then build will be undefined.